# solr terms: boosting and dismax?

Tags: solr

Currently I am learning how [SOLR](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) works.

Words I usually see are boosting and dismax request handler. What do they mean?

I have googled it but found the explanations difficult to understand.

I also read that the dismax handler could search multiple document fields. What does that mean? Doesn't the standard search handler search in multiple fields when I'm querying?

Comment: Based on all your Solr questions, I strongly recommend you slow down and **read** the documentation. Otherwise you'll just end up doing trial-and-error programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at the [Solr relevancy FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ):

- [Should I use the standard or dismax request handler?](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#Should_I_use_the_standard_or_dismax_request_handler)
- [How are documents scored](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_are_documents_scored)
- [How can I increase the score for specific documents](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_increase_the_score_for_specific_documents)